# Stream webcam to website like justin.tv from commandline?

Tags: debian, streaming, webcam

I've got a webcam hooked up to a headless debian box, and I'd love to be able to stream it somewhere like justin.tv so I can't just give people a link and they'll have a video up and viewable and it won't burden my server with a bunch of people connecting to it, that's what justin.tv is for.

I'm not particularly against linking to my home server for some people to view it, but I'd really like to avoid it if I can.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into FFMPEG to generate your RTMP stream, ustream supports this method.
http://community.ustream.tv/ustream/topics/ffmpeg_rtmp_issues